# Algorithm to convert a GeoTIFF file to PNG image format

Tags: image-processing, algorithms

I have a bunch of GeoTIFF files that I am processing into a `TFrecords` format for machine learning. Now I can't put tiffs directly into a TFRecords format and so I have to convert the files to either PNG or JPEG. However, I did not want to generate a big bunch of converted PNG files to clutter up my computer and was hoping to do the conversion of the data **in-memory.**

The GeoTIFF has only 3 bands--it is RGB PanSharpened--so no problem with selecting out the bands I need. When I imported a sample GeoTIFF file into `python` using `rasterio` I found that the range for pixel values was between `[282, 1560]`, which seemed rather high. This is satellite imagery, BTW. Now PNG or JPEG files seem to have pixel ranges of between `[0, 255]` or `[0,1]`, from what I gather. This seems like a simple rescaling of the values to my naive eyes.

So my question is whether anyone could provide the basic algorithm to convert TIFF file pixels into PNG or JPEG pixels. I don't need to worry about the spatial coordinates in this case, so I can treat this as a straight TIFF --> PNG or JPEG conversion.

Could I just divide every TIFF pixel by the max in the range, like 1560? I don't know what the maximum value for a TIFF pixel is, but I could divide by the max otherwise. Or I would have to divide by a factor that maps the range [282, 1560] --> [0, 255], right. So that is just a simple scalar multiplication.

I looked around the web but no one seems to have a basic algorithm for this. I read the file specification for TIFFs and PNGs but could not find the maximum and minimum pixel ranges. All I can find is either people converting the images to new files--using `GDAL` or `gdal_translate` or in some cases using `PIL`. Or other answers fall into using GUI tools like QGIS to again save to new files. But like I said, I would rather not save to a file.

Hopefully someone might know the algorithm to do this conversion manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't put tiffs directly into a TFRecords format...

You can. TFRecords does not know what an "image" is, it simply stores a string of bytes. What this means to higher level applications is up to them.

> When I imported a sample GeoTIFF file into python using `rasterio` I found that the range for pixel values was between `[282, 1560]`, which seemed rather high.

Depending on the kind of data they contain, GeoTIFF images can have higher [colour depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) per pixel. For example, the [SRTM data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission) provide a digital elevation model of the Earth. Each pixel value is associated with the height of a "square" that is 30 by 30 meters (along the equator). The variation of that height over the whole planet is much larger than 256. SRTM's GeoTIFFs have a 16bit colour depth.

> Now PNG or JPEG files seem to have pixel ranges of between `[0, 255]` or `[0,1]`, from what I gather.

PNG and JPEG **can** save 16bit per pixel colour depth images and you can still work with them with libraries such as [osgeo](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/OSGeo_Python_Library) or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Depending on the content of the GeoTIFFs though, the data in PNG format (lossless encoding) might not compress as much as you might expect and with JPEG (lossy encoding) you are going to have to tune the compression to avoid losing any necessary features. In the end, it might be better to just leave the data in GeoTIFF or read them in a `numpy` array and then serialise that straight into TFRecords.

> This seems like a simple rescaling of the values to my naive eyes.
>
> So my question is whether anyone could provide the basic algorithm to convert TIFF file pixels into PNG or JPEG pixels. I don't need to worry about the spatial coordinates in this case, so I can treat this as a straight TIFF --> PNG or JPEG conversion.

Indeed, it has to be a simple linear scaling but this is not a good idea for a number of reasons.

If the absolute values are of importance (for example) then the 8bit dynamic range is simply not adequate.

If your subsequent processing is about learning gradients (for another example), then you are going to have to normalise to the global extrema (**not** the maximum / minimum of each individual file) so that the relative slopes do not change. The danger in doing so is again dynamic range. Although it is possible to squash any numerical range in the interval $0 \dots 1$, when this interval is quantised in 8 bits it is only divided into 256 "steps". If two pixel values differ by less than $\frac{1}{256}$, then they will be assigned to the same "bin". Also, if the dataset contains "spikes", that is the majority of the values are between 20-100 (for example) but there is one value at 10000, then these spikes will "kill" the contrast when you normalise at 8bits. What you will get is a mostly black image with 1 white pixel. Again, it might be possible to remove those spikes but if you have to work with them (e.g. for a multispectral application), then normalising to an 8bit colour depth is not a good idea.

The other thing you would be losing if you went with this option is the transform data. That is, the transform that converts coordinates from image (pixel positions and values) to world coordinates (longitude, latitude, height).

Suppose that your GeoTIFF image ($I$) describes a digital elevation model that has both negative and positive values. The total range of the GeoTIFF would be $max(I)-min(I)$. If $min(I)$ is **not zero** then your $0$ point in the converted data will be "floating". It might be 20 on one image, 42 on another 100 on yet another and so on.

The transformation between two ranges is straigthforward: $O_{x,y} = O_{min} + \frac{I_{x,y}-min(I)}{max(I)+min(I)} \times range(O)$, where $O$ is the output image, $O_{min}$ is the new *desired* minimum and $range(O)$ is the *desired* range.

While the transformation is straightforward, the impact it has on the data and subsequent models can be severe, therefore my recommendation would be to preserve the original numbers as much as possible and only intervene if you are absolutely sure that the transformation will not affect your objectives.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an excellent and very thorough response. Thanks so much. I understand what you mean about the compression of information into a tighter range could obscure some features along the gradient due to 'binning' artifacts. Interestingly enough I did successfully take the original 16bit image, pull it into numpy and pass it into a `TFRecord` format. The problem arose when I tried to test the decoding of the `TFRecord` file and plot the image. When I tried to plot with `matplotlib` I got a blank image because `mpl` clips the pixel ranges.

Comment: @krishnab Thank you, I am glad to hear that this was helpful. Regarding `mpl`, if you are using [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) you can pass `extent`s to (kind of) simulate MATLAB's [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) which displays the image making sure that it scales it within a viewable region (but still, not escaping the dangers we are talking about above).

Comment: Oh cool. Yeah, I can try using `imshow`. I tried using `PIL` before but was getting some strange error--possibly related to how the bands are decoded from the `tfrecords` file and how the bands/channels are assigned. I will give `mpl` a shot.